# cmake error using curl library for libjson-rpc-cpp

Tags: git, curl, cmake

I want to use the `libjson-rpc-cpp`, so I'm trying to make the library with git and cmake as instructed on [this website](http://cinemast.github.io/libjson-rpc-cpp/).

It needs a curl library to work. I'm using `libcurl-7.19.3-win32-ssl-msvc` and placed it in the build directory. But when I do the cmake .. command, I get this error:

> Could NOT find CURL (missing: CURL_LIBRARY CURL_INCLUDE_DIR)

I tried to solve it by searching the web, but it's a bit out of my league.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me when I install libcurl4-openssl-dev:

```
sudo apt-get install libcurl4-openssl-dev
```